# Get-GPO : Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest

Tags: windows, powershell, security

Unable to run Get-GPO on Powershell ISE
the error comes:
****Get-GPO: Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest.****
Can someone help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current user is not a member of the domain against which you're running the query. Try using a domain user of that domain.
From the `get-gpo` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/get-gpo?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

> [...] If the domain of the user that is running the session (or, for startup and shutdown scripts, the computer) is different that sales.contoso.com, a trust must exist between the two domains. The command retrieves the GPO information by contacting the PDC (in the sales.contoso.com domain).

Comment: do you have some video example to how to resolve?..will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be a member of the domain - if you're running with appropriate credentials (such as runas /NetOnly credentials) you can specify both the domain name and server name to use.

More information:
https://david-homer.blogspot.com/2023/08/activedirectory-powershell-error-get.html